# Do Templar skills benefit from increase to physical skill damage?

Tags: diablo-iii

Are all of the Templar follower's skills considered physical element? Does he benefit from +% physical skill damage on his gear? Do his normal attacks benefit?

Comment: You mean if the templar is wearing a ring or amulet that has +% physical skill damage?

Comment: Yes, exactly :)

Comment: @fayze - In that case, the accepted answer is correct and does provide some additional information on the mercenary damage types. The key part to keep in mind is the "if given" because gear on your main character will not apply to them. In my opinion, the best gear for the templar to use is the champion summoning weapon, unity, the band of hallow whispers, and the haunt of vaxo ammy. Given an extraordinary amount of gear, the mercenaries will struggle to even come close to 1% of your damage so there is really no point in building up their damage.

Comment: I have clarified my question, thanks. Obviously stun/slow/vortex/freeze effects are best for him at high levels, but he can still do a little damage :) It can be the difference between clearing a rift in 14:58 and 15:02.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

The Templar uses physical moves, the Enchantress uses Arcane moves and the Scoundrel uses a combination of Poison and Lightning. They deal more damage if given the approprieate +element gear.

Source: http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Followers#Gear_and_stats